# How to code Python to accept only integers?

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm working on a Python 3.4 coding assignment that needs an integer input from the user. I am having trouble figuring out how to make the program accept only integer values; for instance, if the user inputs a float (i.e. `"9.5"`), the program will output, `"That's not an integer! Try again."`

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out what your question is

Comment: It would be a good idea to post the code you have so far, and how you have tried to approach it. That way it's easier for people to point out where  your problem might be.

Comment: Accepts where? From raw_input(), from function parameter, from external file? How should program react if non-integer value was provided? Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I realize how vague the question was--hopefully, the edit elucidates my problem a bit better.

Comment: Thanks, all, for helping me find the solution to this problem!

Comment: It's always a good idea to include a piece of your own code in your question, so that people can see what you've tried. Ideally, make a little program that just focuses on the thing you're having a problem with, so that we can run it for ourselves. If you do that you will be **much** less likely to get down-votes on your question.

Comment: @PM2Ring, alright, I've got that down for future reference. I thought that since this was a simple-type question to a bigger code, it wouldn't need much detailing within the question. Now I know!

Comment: Ideally, a simple description without code would be adequate in this case. Unfortunately, we get lots of people here who expect us to do their work for them. By showing your own code we know you've at least tried to solve your problem yourself & that you're not just here for a hand-out. Also, seeing your code gives us an idea of how advanced your Python knowledge is, which helps us know at what level we should aim our answers.

Answer (score -1):

Simple, use raw_input to get the string input, then call .isdigit() on it to see if it is an int. If it is, cast it to an int, then check it is within the valid range. Stick it all in a while loop so it keeps being called until a valid number is input, and you're all set.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to up-vote, so here's a thanks comment for now!